# Why does the videos played in ubuntu 12.04 show more colour?

Tags: video, vlc, colors, mplayer

When I play videos in VLC or movie player they show more colour which cannot be adjusted. Screen shot below. Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: the problem got solved for Vlc by updating but not for Movie Player. Here is a screenshot: http://goo.gl/yaeBt Check the backgrounds, it cannot be understood due to the colours.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved by updating and installing all the necessary updates available.